# OSGI: while creating JUnit Plug-in Test strange errors occurred

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

When I create new launcher for JUnit Plug-in Tests (in eclipse), set bundle dependencies (including `com.springsource.org.junit`) and run launcher, it fails with exceptions about not resolved `org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824` (Missing required bundle `org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0`). So I have next questions:

1. What for is this bundle needed if I have `com.springsource.org.junit` in dependencies?
2. How can I get rid of this bundle if possible?
3. How can I fix this problem if not possible to get rid?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

OSGi cannot resolve bundle org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0. That is why you get your error message. I have two proposels to fix the problem.

Go to the **Plug-ins** Tab in the JUnit Plug-in Test **Run Configuration**. There select only the bundles you need for your test.

1) In order to get all required bundles(also the referenced bundles) click the Button **Add required Plug-ins**

2) You also have to make sure that all of your bundles/plug-ins are started, when you start your test. Set **Default Auto-Start** to true in the **Plug-ins** Tab. Then all bundles get started with the test. You can also manually configure which bundles you want to start.

3) In order to check if all your bundles have been started correctly, start your test with the programm argument -console and type ss inside the console. This will give you an overview over all bundles.

Comment: I did it in that way but bundle org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824 even wasn't there (in Plug-ins). Maybe somehow eclipse set it as my dependency?

Comment: Well it must be part of your target platform, since eclipse/osgi tries to resolve it. Anyway, org.junit4_4.5.0.v20090824 is not missing. The bundle org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0 is missing. Have you tried to add it manualy?

Comment: These bundles are in the folder Eclipse/plugins/. And they are there! With names like org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar. But in eclipse view Plug-ins there is no org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0 bundle.

Comment: Ok, please make sure that you have selected "plug-ins selected below only" in the "Launch with:" combo box and that you have unchecked "only show selected" in the plug-ins tab. If the plug-in is still missing, try to configure your target platform. Open eclipse preferences and check your target platform under Plug-in Development > Target Platform. The Target Platform is the environment in which your bundle/plug-in gets started.

Comment: I have selected "plug-ins selected below only". My target platform is OK. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have a solution.

Remove any junit plugins from the dependencies tab on MANIFEST.
Search for org.hamcrest. If you have hamcrest in the eclipse/plugins directory, it will now show up.

Add Junit followed by hamcrest..

I hope it helps...